# Negating in /,?(([1-9]-[1-9])|([1-9]))/g

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a string containing a mix of digits and hyphenated digits, like a crossword answer specification, for example `1,2-2` or `1-1,3,4,2-2`

`/,?(([1-9]-[1-9])|([1-9]))/g` is what I've come up to match the string

```
value = value.replace(/,?(([1-9]-[1-9])|([1-9]))/g, '');
```

replaces ok, and I've checked it out in an online tester.

What I really need is to negate this, so I can use it on a keyup event, examine the contents of a textarea and remove characters that don't fit,  so it only allows through characters as in the example.

I've tried `^` where expected, but this it's not doing what I expect, how should I negate the regex so I remove everything that doesn't match?

If there is a better way of doing this I'm open to suggestions too.

Comment: This is quite stupid. What happens when a user writes `1-`? When there is the KeyUp of the `-`, it is cancelled because `1-` isn't correct. These things are done after the user finishes writing a text box and changes focus to another element. OR you let the user insert only `[1-9,-]` (and then, after the focus change, you test the text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = 'hello,1,2,3,4-6,1-1,3,test,4,2-2';
var pattern = /,?(([1-9]-[1-9])|([1-9]))/g;

value.replace(pattern, ''); // "hello,test"
```

You can use [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). With `/g` flag, it returns an array of all the matches, then you can use [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join them.

The problem is that String#match returns null when there is no match, so you have to handle that case and use an empty array so that it can join:

```
(value.match(pattern) || []).join(''); // ",1,2,3,4-6,1-1,3,4,2-2"
```

Note: It may better to check them on `onblur` rather than `onkeyup`. Messing with the text that the user is currently typing will make it annoying. Better to wait for the user to finish typing.

Comment: very helpful answer, I have taken note of your suggestion about onblur too. The array of matches is exactly what I need for the next part of the coding.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test it in JS, but this should return the valid string beginning from the left and as long as valid values are encountered (note that I used `\d` - if you'd like 1-9 only, then use your brackets).

`(?:\d(?:-\d)?,)*\d(?:-\d)?`

E.g. matching this regular expression with the string `"0-1,1,2,3,4-4,2,,1,3--4"` will return `"0-1,1,2,3,4-4,2"` as the first match.